# Functional SaveObject in Scala

Tags: object-oriented, functional-programming, scala, immutability

I came across Java like Scala code that I am trying to refactor to make it functional and immutable.  The first obvious flaw is that it's violating thread safety by using mutable public class level collections.

Those methods (`insText`, `insInt`, etc) look unnecessary and can be removed with higher order function (where function takes in `dd => Int`, `dd => String` type of thing). Class `DDType` is wrong with all mutable variables.  Should I change class level mutable sets to private immutable sets?

Do you agree with those changes and overall refactoring approach?

```
class SaveObject extends Update with QueryFormatter {

  val keys    = mutable.Set[(DomainDictionary, Int   )]()
  val inserts = mutable.Set[(DomainDictionary, String)]()

  implicit def toInt(value:String) = value.toInt
  implicit def toDouble(value:String) = augmentString( value ).toDouble
  implicit def toBool(value:String) = value.toBoolean
  implicit def toTs(value:String) = {
  val date:Date = dateFormat.parse(value)
    new Timestamp(date.getTime)
}
implicit def toDate(value:String):Date = {
  dateFormat.parse(value)
}

def add(dd:DomainDictionary, value:String) = {
// check if its a key
getType(dd) match {
  case x if x.isKey    => id(dd, value)
  case x if x.isText   => insText(dd, value)
  case x if x.isInt    => insInt(dd, value)
  case x if x.isDouble => insDouble(dd, value)
  case x if x.isBool   => insBool(dd, value)
  case x if x.isTs     => insTs(dd, value)
  case x if x.isDate   => insDate(dd, toDate(value))
  case _               =>
    val msg = "Could not convert type for dd %s and value %s".format(dd.id, value)
    throw new Exception(msg)
 }
}
class DDType(dd:DomainDictionary) {
var isKey    = false
     var isText   = false
     var isInt    = false
     var isDouble = false
     var isBool   = false
     var isTs     = false
     var isDate   = false
 }
 def getType(dd:DomainDictionary):DDType = {
   val theType = new DDType(dd)
   val ns = dd.namespace
   val isKey = namespaceMatcher(ns,
   (ns,table,key)=>false.toString,
   (ns,table,key)=>false.toString,
   (ns,table,key)=>if(key == QueryPathfinder.ID) true.toString else false.toString
)


 if(toBool(isKey)){
   theType.isKey = true
 }
 else {
   val ddType = dd.domainDictionaryType
   ddType match {
     case "text" => theType.isText = true
     case "numeric" => theType.isInt = true
     case "alphanumeric" => theType.isText = true
     case "date" => theType.isDate = true
     case "timestamp" => theType.isTs = true
     case "boolean" => theType.isBool = true
     case "currency" => theType.isInt = true
     case _ => {} //this is wrong
   }
 }



theType
}
def id(dd:DomainDictionary, key:Int){
  keys += Tuple2(dd, key)
}
def insText(dd:DomainDictionary, value:String) = {
  inserts += Tuple2(dd,value)
}
def insInt(dd:DomainDictionary, value:Int) = {
    inserts += Tuple2(dd,value.toString)
}
def insDouble(dd:DomainDictionary, value:Double) = {
  inserts += Tuple2(dd,value.toString)
}
def insTs(dd:DomainDictionary, value:Timestamp) = {
  val date = new Date(value.getTime)
  inserts += Tuple2(dd,dateFormat.format(date))
 }
 def insDate(dd:DomainDictionary, value:Date) = {
    inserts += Tuple2(dd,dateFormat.format(value))
 }
  def insBool(dd:DomainDictionary, value:Boolean) = {
    inserts += Tuple2(dd,value.toString)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing a repository with a classifier. The classifier is not doing anything except separating out keys from non-keys. The repository doesn't do anything with what it holds. You convert strings to a particular type and then store them back as strings, without gaining any real value along the way.

`DDType` doesn't seem to do anything except act as a classifier. And it doesn't even do that, as it only translates the string values `"text"`, `"numeric"`, etc, into predicates which are then discarded at the end of the classification.

Without seeing the use case, I can only presume that `add(dd)` is called from time to time and the sets are updated, either into `keys` or into `inserts`.

1. `keys` and `inserts` can be variables that hold immutable Sets. That will improve thread safety a smidgen.
2. Remove the redundant classifer:

   ```
   def add(dd:DomainDictionary, value:String) = {
     dd.domainDictionaryType match {
       case "numeric" => keys = keys + (dd, value.toInt)
       case _ => inserts = inserts + (dd, value)
     }
   }
   ```
3. For full thread safety, use a Repository Pattern, or use Actors.